# How to trigger popup window in the main html page from outside directive in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the main html, there are two popup windows. one piece of code for one window is like this:

```
<div id="new-asset-modal" > 
     <div class="modal-dialog"> 
      <div class="modal-content"> 
       <div class="modal-header> 
        <h4 class="modal-title>Type A Record Name</h4> 
       </div> 
       <div class="modal-body"> 
        <input ng-model="a" type="text" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" /> 
       </div> 
       <div class="modal-footer"> 
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button> 
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" id="modal-save" ng-click="add()">Save</button> 
       </div> 
      </div> 
     </div> 
    </div>
```

Ofcourse, there are anther modal called "Type B Record Name"

In the main html, I used directive like this

```
<directivetest></directivetest>
```

In the control, code is like this:

```
  .directive("directivetest",function(){
                    return{
                    restrict:'EA',
                    replace: true,
                    templateUrl: "testpage.html",
                    controller:[ $scope,function($scope){
                    $scope.popaction=function(c){.....};
                     }]
    }
    );}
```

In the testpage.html, there is a button

```
<button ng-click="popaction(c);">Button1</button>
```

I want a function like this: When Button1 is pressed, if the argument equals to "a",then "Type A modal" is triggered/shown in the main page; if the argument equals to "b", then "Type B modal" is triggerd/shown.

Thank!!

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to `$broadcast` a message from your directive that contains the type that was clicked and then use `$on` in your main controller to listen for the message and act accordingly when received.

In the directive controller:

```
$scope.popaction=function(type){
    $scope.$broadcast("BUTTON_CLICKED", {"type":type});
};
```

In the main controller:

```
$scope.$on("BUTTON_CLICKED", function(event, args) {
    if(args.type === 'a') {
        doModalA();
    }
});
```

**Update**
As far as how to trigger the modal, I've used [ng-dialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog) and really liked it.  The documentation is pretty good but basically you include the js file and inject `ngDialog`, then do something like:

```
function doModalA() {
    ngDialog.open({ template: 'popupTmpl.html' });
}
```

You can also use `ngDialog.openConfirm` and wait for a promise to return so you can perform actions based on the users interactions with your modal.  You can also pass it data, your scope, give the modal it's own controller, and much more.  It can be used very simply but it's very flexible to do more complex things.

Lastly, you'll probably have to make templates out of your modals, which is easy. Just include something like this in your main.html, put your modal content in it, and name it whatever you want:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/popupTmpl.html">
    Content of the template.
</script>
```

Comment: Thx for the help. What would be "doModalA();" like? I dont know how to trigger that modal DOM. @csmithmaui